# cvCapturefromCAM() returns NULL

Tags: opencv

Iam using cvCapturefromCAM() to display the camera video. But if some VT(video) call is made, cvCapturefromCAM() is returning NULL. according to my analysis it is like, if the camera has already been started , capture will return NULL. so while doing video call, camera has bee started by the videoengine lib. And i donot hav the cvCapture pointer also to release the camera. Please help me how to go about this deadlock..

thanks
gayathri devi

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make a pointer to `cvCapturefromCAM()` and then after use, release it. That's it.

Like this:

```
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Make this modification and it should work. I also had this issue before.

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
```